# Is it possible to pass an argument to a polymer behavior?

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0

It's not to a function from an attribute.

Inside a Polymer Element, I have something like this:

```
 this.$.register.addEventListener('iron-form-presubmit',
                   function() {
                       //Hides the element...
                       this.$$('#js-error-username-invalid, #js-error-message').setAttribute('style', 'display:none');
                       //Removes the invalid attribute
                       setInvalid(this.root, false);
                   });

               //What to do when a form returns an error, such as the username does not exist.
               this.$.register.addEventListener('iron-form-error', function (event) {
                   //Sends invalid to everyone.
                   setInvalid(this.root, true);
                   console.log(event);
                   this.$$("#js-error-message").removeAttribute('style');
                   this.$$("#js-error-message").innerHTML = event.detail.request.xhr.response.error_description
                });
```

Now I want to define a behavior on **a separate file** that has a function like this:

```
 _setError : function(query) {
            var elems = Array.prototype.slice.call(Polymer.dom(this.root).querySelectorAll(query));
            elems.forEach(function(element) {
                element.setAttribute('invalid', '');

            });
        }
```

All those querySelectors, I'd like to pass them as argument so I can reuse this logic almost everywhere where I have a form. I've tried digging into some files but I haven't found anything that has helped me with.

Answer (score 1):

Answer was so simple:

If you have the behavior :

```
MyBehavior.FormSubmit = {
        _hello : function(ma) {
            alert(ma);
        },
```

Just call it like this:

```
MyBehavior.FormSubmit_hello("Hi :D");
```